# QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLv3_client_method RAILS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, wkhtmltopdf

I have a problem about wkhtmltopdf. i used the wkhtmltopdf like this in my docker.

```
wkhtmltopdf https://www.google.com google.pdf
```

and then there are some errors like these below

```
QSslSocket: cannot resolve CRYPTO_num_locks                  ] 10%
QSslSocket: cannot resolve CRYPTO_set_id_callback
QSslSocket: cannot resolve CRYPTO_set_locking_callback
QSslSocket: cannot resolve sk_free
QSslSocket: cannot resolve sk_num
QSslSocket: cannot resolve sk_pop_free
QSslSocket: cannot resolve sk_value
QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSL_library_init
QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSL_load_error_strings
QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLv3_client_method
QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLv23_client_method
QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLv3_server_method
QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLv23_server_method
QSslSocket: cannot resolve X509_STORE_CTX_get_chain
QSslSocket: cannot resolve OPENSSL_add_all_algorithms_noconf
QSslSocket: cannot resolve OPENSSL_add_all_algorithms_conf
QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLeay
QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function CRYPTO_num_locks
QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function CRYPTO_set_id_callback
QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function CRYPTO_set_locking_callback
QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function SSL_library_init
QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function SSLv23_client_method
QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function sk_num
QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function SSLv23_client_method
QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function SSL_library_init
Error: Failed loading page https://www.google.com (sometimes it will work just to ignore this error with --load-error-handling ignore)
Exit with code 1 due to network error: UnknownNetworkError
QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function CRYPTO_num_locks
QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function CRYPTO_set_id_callback
QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function CRYPTO_set_locking_callback
```

and then i red some stackoverflow and github discussion. and then i installed the libssl1.0-dev library by

```
apt-get install -y libssl1.0-dev
```

then my errors became more less then before

```
Loading pages (1/6)
QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLv3_client_method               ] 10%
QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLv3_server_method
Counting pages (2/6)                                               
Resolving links (4/6)                                                       
Loading headers and footers (5/6)                                           
Printing pages (6/6)
Done
```

but why there is still error like this

```
QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLv3_client_method               ] 10%
```

i red some github and stackoverflow and github discussion it must be solved just by install the libssl library.

is this safe error?
or there is some solution to that? 
kindly need your help. thanks

this is my docker kernel

```
Linux 3c28a7f3c2e6 4.9.125-linuxkit #1 SMP Fri Sep 7 08:20:28 UTC 2018 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

my version of wkhtmltopdf

```
wkhtmltopdf 0.12.4 (with patched qt)
```

and this is my openssl version (and i still dont understand how it linked to open ssl but i will let you know my openssl version hehehe)

```
OpenSSL 1.1.0j  20 Nov 2018
```

Answer (score 0):

check open-ssl-devel, if exist remove it.